# I am trying to format 2d list items into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I am doing a simple enough task by trying to write out a message using items from a 2d list as shown below

```
catalogue = [["Lenova Yoga Tablet", 4000], ["Macbook Air", 8000], ["Apple iPad", 500], ["Samsung Galaxy A7", 200]]

for i in catalogue:
   print("{}. {}, {}".format(str(i+1), catalogue[i][0], str(catalogue[i][1])))
```

I am being returned an error saying the following:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

It seems to think I am trying to add something to the list. Mind you I have not coded in a couple years so maybe syntax has changed or I am just missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: Your `i` is a sublist of `catalogue` (i.e. `["Lenova Yoga Tablet", 4000]`) and you are adding `int` to it. Perhaps you want `for i, n in enumerate(catalogue)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate`. If you want to start from `1` use `enumerate(catalogue, 1)`

**Ex:**

```
catalogue = [["Lenova Yoga Tablet", 4000], ["Macbook Air", 8000], ["Apple iPad", 500], ["Samsung Galaxy A7", 200]]

for i, value in enumerate(catalogue):
    print("{}. {}, {}".format(i, value[0], value[1]))
```

---

Or by unpacking the items in sub-list

**Ex:**

```
for i, (item, price) in enumerate(catalogue):
    print("{}. {}, {}".format(i, item, price))
```

**Output:**

```
0. Lenova Yoga Tablet, 4000
1. Macbook Air, 8000
2. Apple iPad, 500
3. Samsung Galaxy A7, 200
```

Comment: For future reference is enumerate a built-in function. I learnt pyhton about 4 years ago and stopped coding 2 years ago and as far as i can remember for similar things i never had to use an enumerate function. What has changed since then and now for this to happen if you dont mind me asking.

Comment: Yes. `enumerate` is a  build-in method. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1):

We iterate over the `catalogue` then we iterate over that iteration - we want to make sure that program will not crash when there will be more or less than 3 elements. at the end, we are using the `join()` function to print the result.

```
catalogue = [["Lenova Yoga Tablet", 4000], ["Macbook Air", 8000], ["Apple iPad", 500], ["Samsung Galaxy A7", 200]]

for i in catalogue:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
       temp.append(str(j))
    print(''.join(temp))
```

Comment: That code is printing out the following:
"Lenova Yoga Tablet,

Lenova Yoga Tablet4000,

Macbook Air,

Macbook Air8000,

Apple iPad,

Apple iPad500

Samsung Galaxy A7,

Samsung Galaxy A7200"

Unfortunately im hazey on some of the more complex things in python as i havent coded in a while and do not understand this piece of code very well. Could you explain why this may be hapenning and how I could go about fixing this. The apostrophe is a new line, I am just having a hard time formatting the comment

Comment: It prints all elements of one nested list in 1 string. At first, we iterate over the `catalogue` to get the access to the nested lists. We create an empty lists `temp` Then we iterate in nested lists and we append every element from it to the `temp`. That could be also done using the list comprehension `temp = [str(x) for x in i]`. After all, elements are appended to the `temp` we are using the `join()` function which joins all elements `in-line` as we added the `''` at the beginning. We finally print that and got the result.

Comment: @UmairAhmed good job by accepting someone's else's answer :)

Comment: Sorry dude, I really appreciate the help I just feel that Rakesh's solution was a lot simpler and helped me directly solve the problem better. Thank you for your time and explanations.

Comment: @UmairAhmed as you wish if you treat the answer with `format` as the proper one, go on and accept it using the old methods that are worse than moderns :))

Comment: @Rakesh yes it is an old method. The modern method that is recommended to use is `f string`.